# how to create default constraint for each table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have around 150 tables in my database and now I need to add a column constraint(InsertedOn) on to each and every table with a default value of GetDate()

I have tried below code to accomplish the task

```
exec sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? ADD CONSTRAINT DF_InsertedOn DEFAULT GetDate() FOR [InsertedOn]';
```

But my problem is constraint name,The above code fails when its trying to create the constraint for the second table since the name of the constraint in use

Is there any way to accomplish the task using the same **sp_msforeachtable** ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + 'ALTER TABLE [' + s.name + '].[' + o.name  + '] 
        ADD [InsertedOn] DATETIME NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_' + o.name + '_InsertedOn] DEFAULT GETDATE()'
    FROM sys.objects o WITH (NOWAIT)
    JOIN sys.schemas s WITH (NOWAIT) ON o.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
    WHERE NOT EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM sys.columns c WITH (NOWAIT)
            WHERE c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
                AND c.name = 'InsertedOn'
        )
        AND o.[type] = 'U'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

PRINT @SQL
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL
```

Output -

```
ALTER TABLE [tt].[t1] 
ADD [InsertedOn] DATETIME NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_t1_InsertedOn] DEFAULT GETDATE()
ALTER TABLE [tt].[t2] 
ADD [InsertedOn] DATETIME NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_t2_InsertedOn] DEFAULT GETDATE()
```

Comment: Tanks Devart its doing the job..
But i wonder if i can use '?' parameter for the constraint name as we use for the table name
exec sp_msforeachtable 'ALTER TABLE ? ADD CONSTRAINT ? DEFAULT GetDate() FOR [InsertedOn]';

Comment: `sp_MSforeachtable` is undocumented, so I can't answer on your question.

Answer (score 3):

To generate scrips you can use this code. It uses system views [sys.tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), [sys.schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176011.aspx) and [sys.columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100) = 'InsertedOn'

SELECT
    'ALTER TABLE ' + s.name + '.' + t.name + 
    ' ADD CONSTRAINT DF_' + t.name + '_' + @ColumnName + 
    ' DEFAULT GetDate() FOR ' + @ColumnName
FROM sys.tables t
JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM sys.columns c
        WHERE c.object_id = t.object_id
            AND name = @ColumnName
    )
```